# Crear y mantener una sesion en JSP java web

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Al crear la sesion en el login.jsp y al redireccionar al index.jsp bota nulo la sesion "usuario

```
 LOGIN.JSP

       HttpSession sesion_usuario = request.getSession(true); 
                    sesion_usuario.setAttribute("usuario", login_usuario);
                    String return_url = request.getAttribute("redirect") == null ? "index.jsp" :(String) request.getAttribute("redirect");
                    response.sendRedirect(return_url); "


INDEX:JSP
    UsuarioControlador uc=new UsuarioControlador();
    ArrayList<String> lista_deseos=new ArrayList();
    if(sesion.getAttribute("usuario")!=null){
        usuario=(Usuario) sesion.getAttribute("usuario");
        lista_deseos = sesion.getAttribute("wishlist") == null ? uc.get_user_listadeseos(usuario.get_user_codigo()) : (ArrayList) sesion.getAttribute("wishlist");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

vi que trabajo con sesiones y mantener su sesión, me pregunto si ha conseguido lograr su objetivo o como fue que lo soluciono, yo estoy trabajando con java web, jsf y tengo la misma situación, como puedo mantener mi sesión cuando trabajan en algún formulario, no he podido solventar el problema que tengo

Comment: Este es un espacio para respuestas. Si tienes alguna pregunta similar, tienes la libertad de postearla en el sitio siguiendo los lineamientos de [ask].